# Minicom runscript does not understand variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to execute a simple runsript that reads in a variable $1 and passes it out as serial data using the "send" command. I've had no issues sending text with that command in a script, but I dont want to write multiple scripts just to send different things. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right.
here's the code I thought it should be: (file is commands.sh)

```
#!bin/bash
send "$1\c"
```

when I run minicom -S commands.sh "flick servo"
i get:

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

any ideas? I'm open to alternate ways to send text via terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is a minicom runscript, not a shell script. Naming the script `.sh` or adding a comment saying `!bin/bash` does not change this. `-S` also doesn't accept arguments.

If (and only if) you can successfully run `minicom -S hardcodedscript`, you can use environment variables to parameterize it:

Make a `commands.rs`:

```
send "$(THING)\c"
```

then

```
THING='flick servo' minicom -S commands.rs
```

Comment: I'll have to look into environment variables. For now Im just using hardcoded text